# How do you show that a language is in the class P?

Tags: big-o, time-complexity, complexity-theory

I have two languages:

```
A = { <M, w> | M accepts w after running for at most 2^500 steps }
B = { <M, w, 1^t> | M accepts w after running for at most t steps }
```

I need to figure out if these languages are in the class P. I know a language is in the class P if it runs in poly-time. I'm pretty sure the language A runs in exponential time but I'm not quite sure if a constant like 2^500 makes it poly-time instead.

Any help appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Algorithmic time is expressed as a function of the input size. If, for any input, A takes 2^500 steps, then it is actually constant time (no matter what the input, the running time is constant), which is definitely in P.

B takes t steps, where t is presumably the size of the input, so it is linear time (the time increases linearly with the input size), which is also in P.

If you have a problem that requires, for example, 2^t steps or t! (factorial) steps, then it is NOT in P. Look up Big O notation

Comment: Some of the text was being interpreted as markup. I've edited the question so it displays properly.

Comment: The corrected markup invalidates some parts of your answer where you made wrong assumptions about what it was supposed to look like; you might want to address that.

Comment: I re-checked it, I'm not sure where it doesn't match the question, it still says A takes 2^500 steps and B takes t steps, though now it says 1^t for B... not sure what that means since 1^x is 1 for any x, but maybe I'm misunderstanding the notation.

Comment: The language A is the set of all pairs `<M, w>`, where `M` describes a Turing machine that halts on input `w` after at most `2^500` steps. The issue is whether a Turing machine can decide whether an input is such a pair in polynomial time, not whether M halts in polynomial time. The question for B is similar.

Answer (score 2):

A language is in **P**, if there exist an algorithm, that can decide if a given input belongs to the language and runs in polynomial time. Polynomial time, means that you can find an upper bound by an polynomial function in the length of the input.

To address your example:

1. Define the algorithm `AL₁` as:
   For the element `<M,w>` run `M(w)`.

   Since `M(w)` takes at most a constant number `c = 2⁵⁰⁰` steps, the complexity  of `AL₁` is bounded by a constant number, which is polynomial. `AL₁ ∈ O(1)`. So `A` is in **P**.
2. Define algorithm `AL₂` as:
   For the element `<M,w,1t>` run `M(w,1t)`.

   Since `M(w,1t)` takes at most `t` steps, we have to bring the input length and `t` together. Notice, that the input consists of `w` and `1t`. `1t` means that the number `t` is input as unary (e.g. 1⁵ = 11111₁ = 5₁₀). This is important for the input length. E.g. the length of `1²⁵⁶` is `256`, but the length of `256 = 2⁸` is only `8 = log₂(256)` in binary.
   So the input length is `len(w) + t` and `AL₂ ∈ O(t)` holds. So the complexity of `AL₂` is also bounded by a polynomial and so the language `B` is in **P**.

Let me add an example to show haw important it is to differ between unary and other numeral systems.

```
C = { <M, w, t> | M accepts w after running for at most t steps }
```

`C` is basically like `B`, but `t` is not in unary numeral system, so the length of `t` is `logc(t)`. The basis `c` of the logarithm does not matter, because it results only in a constant factor.

The input length is now `len(w) + log(t)`, so `O(t)` is not necessary polynomial in the input length. Lets say `len(w)` is a constant number (for simplification) , then `t = clogc(t)` is exponential in the input length and thus `C` is *not* in **P**.

Comment: Simulating a Turing Machine with another Turing machine has overhead; I don't think you're accounting for that. It doesn't change whether or not the languages are in P, but it changes the analysis a little.

Comment: @user2357112 you are right. But there are some different ways to define languages. In most cases I saw, the Turing machine is not part of the elements in the language. So I decided to take the whole element containing the machine and added an external one. I think it is possible to have many different turing machines `M`, so if I don't use a new turing machine, it could be possible that I need a different one for every element in the language. However, the way I used gets rid of the problem, if it is a problem :)